# Adding appendix in TOC as Appendix A, Appendix B using appendix package

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I am writing my thesis, I want to add appendix after the references in TOC.

I want the appendix in following format

> Appendix A                       107
>
> Appendix B                       115
>
> Appendix C                       120

How I can do this using [`appendix`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendix) package?

Comment: Try `\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}`

Comment: I tried but after adding package, which code i need to add appendix Appendix A 107

Appendix B 115

Appendix C 120

Comment: I don't know the way of adding appendix in TOC using appendix package as desired.....

Comment: After adding the instruction `\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}`, did you recompile your document *twice* to fully update the Table of Contents?

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: yes i compile, i add the package bt i dont know how to add appendix in the document and appendix eenvoirnment, plz help me

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of how to use the `appendix` package.

Insert your appendices inside the environment `appendices`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only for the example

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{First section}
\lipsum

\begin{appendices}

\section{First appendix}
\lipsum

\section{Second appendix}
\lipsum

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

And this is how the Table of Contents will look like:

[image]